# Background image with filters not stretching to full width of canvas - fabric.js

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs, imagefilter

I am using fabric.js.
I am loading a background image into canvas and the image is not streching. 
If i upload just the image everything is good, when i add filters to background image, the background image not stretching to full width of the canvas.

I tried to add filters after loading the image.
Tried also remove background and load again, everything is going to the same place... Image not stretching.

This is a fiddle with only background image:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/Music/6mcf4kj0/2/`
```

This is a fiddle with background image and filters:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/Music/q30cfwL7/1/`
```

I expect the image to be full width and height of the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is 3000x3000, which is too large for the default fabric.js settings. From the [filter docs](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-filters):

> The picture will be painted over a tile of 2048x2048 size, bigger
> pictures won't fit. fabric.textureSize set at 2408 is a safe limit.
> Most of the hardware will support 4096 and so 4096x4096 is a limit
> that will probably work and give you less headaches. Take in mind that
> canvas has a max size too. If you are supporting browsers like IE11
> you will have probably problems with canvases bigger than 5000 on a
> size, whatever your webgl hardware is capable of.

Try this before applying the filter:

```
fabric.textureSize = 4096
```

You can also check if Webgl is supported then apply

```
if (fabric.isWebglSupported()) fabric.textureSize = 65536;
```

Comment: this worked for me,  i found this code though -   if (fabric.isWebglSupported()) fabric.textureSize = 65536;